# How can I numerically implement $\delta(f(x,y))$

Tags: numerical-methods, dirac-delta

I would like to numerically implement a Dirac Delta function whose argument is another 2 variable function. I know that I can model a Dirac Delta numerically using a Gaussian. What can I do if I want to implement $\delta(f(x,y))$. Will using a function like $e^{-f(x,y)^2/\sigma^2}$ work?
Edit: $\sigma$ is a parameter I can control to make the peak of the Gaussian sharper. By 'implement', I mean generate numerically, that is to generate a 2 variable Delta function over a 2D grid.

Comment: What meaning do you give to *implement* ? And what is $\sigma$ ?

Comment: Provide more background and context, please.

Comment: It would be best to avoid explicitly implementing distributions. Use partial integration or other methods to integrate them up to at least regular functions. For ODE this could look like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2023312/115115 or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2834640/115115. Of course, here with the composite distribution things are a little more involved.

Comment: You are aware that in this formulation you get a delta "wall" along a curve $f(x,y)=0$? // For any non-negative function $\phi$ with integral one, the delta approximation is $\phi(x/σ)/σ$ for $σ\to 0$, leading to the composition $\phi(f(x,y)/σ)/σ$ for the "delta wall". // It is not clear if what you are doing is well-defined. For any smooth test function, what would you expect $\int g(x,y)\delta(f(x,y))d(x,y)$ to be? To compare, for one-dimensional functions with simple roots we know $\delta(f(x))=\sum_{a:f(a)=0}\frac{\delta(x-a)}{|f'(a)|}$.

Comment: If the goal is to integrate $\delta(f(x, y)) \phi(x, y)$, you can reduce the problem to a line integral. If you know how to parametrize $f(x, y) = 0$, you get a one-dimensional definite integral.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac delta function $\delta$ is a linear *functional* which maps your functions into your scalars. To be precise, suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then the functional $T : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$T(f) = f(x_0)$$ is the Dirac delta function with respect to the point $x_0$. The term functional rather than function is used to emphasize that the codomain of $T$ is your set of scalars. It is clear that $T$ is linear, because $$T(af + bg) = a f(x_0) + b g(x_0) = a T(f) + b T(g)$$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f, g \in V$.

---

Many, many functionals $S : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be written exactly as
$$ S(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) s(x)dx$$
for a suitable choice of $s$. Dirac's delta function is an exception. It can be approximated using such functionals or you can simply implement it using the definition.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, exactly: if the delta function $\delta$ can be well-approximated by a gaussian function $N$, then $\delta(f(x,y)) \approx N(f(x,y)) = \frac{1}{Z_0}\exp{(-f(x,y)^2/\sigma^2)}$, with $Z_0$ a normalizing factor.

The only difficulty I can see is that depending on the possible values of $f$, it may be important for your application to have a sharper gaussian function $N$.

Comment: You need to at least add the constant factor that integrates the delta approximation to one over the real line.